# How to center Bootstrap col-md-4 and form-group with two input groups and a button, keep all three inline

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to keep two input groups and a button inline and centred using Bootstrap 3, I have the following that I've been fiddling with but I cannot keep the button inline with the input boxes

```
<section id="search_section">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form class="form-inline">

            <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="input-group">
                      <div class="input-group-addon">Criteria</div>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Any Criteria">
                  </div>
                  <div class="input-group">
                      <div class="input-group-addon">Location</div>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Any Location">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
              </div>



            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution

```
                 <section id="search_section">                 
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <form class="form-inline">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                  <div class="input-group col-md-4">
                                      <div class="input-group-addon">Criteria</div>
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Any Criteria">
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="input-group col-md-4">
                                      <div class="input-group-addon">Location</div>
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Any Location">
                                  </div>
                                  <button type="submit col-md-4" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
                              </div>

                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                   </div>
                </section>
```

just you need to add classes col-md-4 to each form group item